# Android: How to display full screen progress bar in center

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display progress bar with custom theme. But it is coming in top left corner instead of center. If I don't use custom theme it will come in center but not full screen, which displays textviews and other elements in background which looks bad. The following is the code and screenshot

Custom Theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In activity initialising progress dialog with custom theme:

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context, R.layout.layout_progress_dialog);
progressBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
progressBar.setCancelable(false);
```

[image]

When I see the preview of progress bar theme alone it shows correctly as below. But in activity it shows in wrong position.

[image]

Comment: That should've done the job. Where do you see progressbar in design tab?

Comment: @MehulMohan I have added the screenshot of design

Comment: That is strange. Try to add `android:gravity="center"` to relativelayout

Comment: Hi,I tried with all solutions but still same issue. How u made it center align?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the id of a layout in a constructor that requires the id of a theme.

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context, R.layout.layout_progress_dialog);
```

The constructor is

```
public ProgressDialog(Context context, int theme)
```

You should define your custom attributes in style.xml and pass the id of that style here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<include/>` tag to add the progress bar to your activity's layout and set it's location. If your custom style is `customProgressDialog.xml` :

```
<include
    layout="@layout/customProgressDialog"
    android:id="@+id/customProgressDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
```

Then in your activity :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = (ProgressDialog) findViewById(R.id.customProgressDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a cleaner solution.

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="your_desire_value"
        android:background="your_background_color" />
```

Then you can change the size of the progress bar with padding. The larger the padding, the smaller the size.
And you don't have to add a layout to wrap the progress bar.